# Vim - mapping for moving between buffers silently

Tags: vim, shortcuts, vimrc, buffer

in my .vimrc I have the following mapping to move between buffers:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-b> :bp<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-n> :bn<CR>
```

This mapping works but it outputs some info about the files that I'm not interest in. Is there a way to suppress these infos and not show them?

Here's a link a gif that shows the problem http://cl.ly/image/0D2Z3l2q143T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-b> :silent :bp<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-n> :silent :bn<CR>
```

Where `<silent>` silence printing of the mapping and `:silent` silence printing of the command info.